# How to access a field in a database table in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, api, xaml, xamarin.forms

How can I access a specific row of the database table of my choice in Xamarin Forms?
I have a table in the database that contains the columns: Title, URL image, ID
I did everything in the API and I so did in Xamarin Forms.
My view page in Xamarin Forms contains a grid.
I emphasize that I do not want to use the list and I want to manually give the information to the  buttons and it is not in order.
I appreciate those who guide me!

my table:

```
    public class ButtonCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int ButtonCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string ButtonCategoryTitle { get; set; }
        public string ButtonCategoryImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

my code in api:

```
        [HttpGet("GetCategories")]
        public List<ButtonCategory> GetCategories()
        {
            return context.ButtonCategories.ToList();
        }
```

I copy My Table in Xamarin:

```
    public class ButtonCategory
    {
        
        public int ButtonCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string ButtonCategoryTitle { get; set; }
        public string ButtonCategoryImageUrl { get; set; }

    }
```

and then I connect to Api:

```
   public   class ButtonHelper
    {
  
        public async  Task<List<ButtonCategory>> GetButtonCategoryAsync()
        {

            string Url = "http://111.111.1.111:1111/api/Buttons/GetCategories";

            var client = new HttpClient();

            var Uri = new Uri(Url);

            var result = await client.GetStringAsync(Uri);

            var newresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ButtonCategory>>(result);

           return newresult.ToList();
         }
           
    }
```

and My Ui:

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
     
            <StackLayout >
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Black" ColumnSpacing="10" RowSpacing="10" Padding="15">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ImageButton  Source="{Binding }" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  CornerRadius="30"/>


                    <ImageButton  Source="{Binding}" Aspect="AspectFill"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="30"/>


                    <ImageButton Source="{Binding }" Aspect="AspectFill"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="30" />

                    <ImageButton Source="{Binding }" Aspect="AspectFill"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="30"/>

                    <ImageButton Source="{Binding}" Aspect="AspectFill"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="30" />

                    <ImageButton Source="{Binding}" Aspect="AspectFill"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="30"/>
                    

                </Grid>

            </StackLayout>
    
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

I want  photo second row  the database table  in the first row button of the second Weston. And the photo of the fifth row of the database table should be placed in the button of the first row of the first column And I choose the rest in the same way!

Comment: You queried the database and your response was a controller which put the data into a List<FoodsCategory>.  So each row of the database is one instance of the class FoodsCategory.  Id is a key so you would need something like : GetCategories()[id]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Was there no problem with my solution? Can you write an example according to my code? @jdweng

Comment: The only issue with your code is looking up the one row in the response from the database.  So you have a List<FoodsCategory> and just need to get the one row.  Since the class has a key you can lookup by the key.

Comment: I did this but it does not work, maybe the problem is with my code, if you can write me an example, thank you! @ jdweng

Comment: Try following : ButtonCategory button123 = context.ButtonCategories.Where(x => x.ButtonCategoryId = 123).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Do I have to write this code in the code behind the UI page? And how to use it in View? I have access to the database in Xamarin via API! @jdweng

Comment: The code is just getting the ButtonCategory from the Entity class.  You have to bind the properties to your button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use an indexer to specify a specific item within your list

```
<ImageButton  Source="{Binding myButtons[2].ButtonCategoryImageUrl}" ... />
```

in your code behind

```
// create a myButtons property
List<ButtonCategory> myButtons { get; set; }

// then in your OnAppearing
myButtons = await GetButtonCategoryAsync();
this.BindingContext = this;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My question to you is what is (myButtons)? @Jason

Comment: your `List<ButtonCategory>`.  Presumably you have a property on your VM/BindingContext that contains this data

Comment: Do you mean the code behind the page xaml?

Comment: I have no idea how your page's code is setup.  But if you want to use data binding you have to have a BindingContext

Comment: I went according to your method but it was not done! Is it possible for you to give me an example of (myButtons)? Maybe I am wrong in writing the code!

Comment: see expanded example

Comment: Answered for me via indexer! Can it be accessed via Title or ID?

Comment: not in a binding expression - you possibly could create a value converter to do it